# How can I disable transition from auto to a value in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, transition

Since most browsers can't transition from auto to a value I designed my site according to that. But Safari (Version 8.0 (10600.1.25)) transitioning them and it breaks my design.

```
    body {
 margin: 12px 0;
  position:relative;
  width:1000px;
}
.card-container {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left:auto;
  /*Uncomment to view transition in safari*/
  /* left:500px; */
  background: #acacac;
  transition: left 1s;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbqJMB

Is there a workaround?

Comment: IIRC, Safari is doing it right according to the spec.

Comment: Thanks. But its breaking my design. I am trying to solve it.